# How do I create an empty project in Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode6

Xcode 6.0 doesn’t have an option to create an empty project like in Xcode 5.1.

How do I create an empty project?

Comment: As there's no template for empty application in `XCode 6.0`. So, as I did, You must take storyBoard application .then remove `storyBoard` and add your `xibs` in project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File -> New -> Project - > Single View Application

Fill the fields. Click accept.

- Delete Main.storyboard
- Delete YourProjectName.xcdatamodeld
- Delete LaunchScreen.xib